# reading entire text file using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to read a text file using vba. I tried the below code

```
Open "C:\tester.txt" For Input As #1
Worksheets("UI").Range("H12").Value = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
Close #1
```

When I run this I'm getting an error.

Run-time error '62'. Input past end of file.

The content of text file is:

> Unable to open COM10. Make sure it is connected
>     Plus other stuff
>     And more stuff
>     way more stuff

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: This previous answer on the same subject might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba

Comment: Thanks Hansen. But my text file may have multiple lines. In the post link given by you I can only read one line. But I want to read the entire text file. My text file can have multiple lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing 100 text files into Excel at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410503/importing-100-text-files-into-excel-at-once)

Comment: See the array method mentioned in the above link

Comment: same method can be seen here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128115/input-past-end-of-file-vba-excel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code will loop through each line in the text document and print these from range `H12` and downward in the UI-sheet.

```
Sub ImportFromText()
    Open "C:\tester.txt" For Input As #1
    r = 0
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, Data
        Worksheets("UI").Range("H12").Offset(r, 0) = Data
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Thanks again. Your code works!!.. but I'm getting two additional characters in the first line. My first line output looks like this
    ÿþUnable to open  COM10. Make sure it is connected.

I tried using the trim fucntion and worksheets.clean method but it is not removing those additional charecters. any help on this?

Comment: I used this
    Worksheets("UI").Range("H12").Value = Right(Worksheets("UI").Range("H12").Value, Len(Worksheets("UI").Range("H12").Value) - 2)

Thanks for all your help.. setting your answer as the right answer.

Comment: The two characters appears because because you are reading from a unicode text document. To avoid this you would have to use the `OpenTextFile` method which can open and understand the unicode format. This is, however, an entirely different syntax from what you are using now.

Answer (score 17):

Rather than loop cell by cell, you can read the entire file into a variant array, then dump it in a single shot.

Change the path from `C:\temp\test.txt` to suit.

```
Sub Qantas_Delay()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objTF As Object
Dim strIn 'As String
Dim X

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\test.txt", 1)
strIn = objTF.readall
X = Split(strIn, vbNewLine)
[h12].Resize(UBound(X) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(X)
objTF.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey brettdj, When I ran your code I get "ÿþU" in H12, no matter what is the content of the test file. Any suggestion on how to format it?

Comment: Can you make your test file  available?

Comment: + 1 Much better method than looping... A similar approach (faster than fso) is mentioned in the two links below op's question...

Answer (score 9):

More Slightly modified for those who do not like VBA to have to make up explicit variables and then waste time transfer data to them.. Let With. do the job

```
Function LoadFileStr$(FN$)

  With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

          LoadFileStr = .OpenTextFile(FN, 1).readall

        End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

brettdj's answer, slightly adjusted

```
Public Function readFileContents(ByVal fullFilename As String) As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objTF As Object
    Dim strIn As String

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fullFilename, 1)
    strIn = objTF.readall
    objTF.Close

    readFileContents = strIn
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

To read line by line:

```
Public Sub loadFromFile(fullFilename As String)

    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim DataLine As String

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open fullFilename For Input As #FileNum

    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
        Debug.Print DataLine
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub LoadFile() ' load entire file to string
' from Siddharth Rout
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128115/
    Dim MyData As String
    Open "C:\MyFile" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1)) ' sets buffer to Length Of File
    Get #1, , MyData ' fits exactly
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: this works, but text file comes in with spaces inserted between every character

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier alternative is `Data` > `From Text` and you can specify how often the data is refreshed in the Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Fidel's answer, over Brettdj's answer, adjusted for ASCII or Unicode and without magical numbers:

```
Public Function readFileContents(ByVal fullFilename As String, ByVal asASCII As Boolean) As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objTF As Object
    Dim strIn As String

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fullFilename, IOMode:=ForReading, format:=IIf(asASCII, TristateFalse, TristateTrue))
    strIn = objTF.ReadAll
    objTF.Close
    readFileContents = strIn
End Function
```