# Saving Array into a file in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do I save a 4x4 array and a single integer to a file in visual basic?

I am making 2048 in visual basic. I have a 4x4 array called "Grid" and an integer variable called score. I wish to be able to save my game and continue where I left off. How would I save the contents of the array to a file and then load it back in, along with the score?

Comment: What have you did so far?

Comment: Not helpful....

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We're here to help you solve a problem. If you want someone to write code for you, pay them.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how to create a txt file with a grid and load it.

You need to tailor this to your need, especially the return from `LoadTxtFile` which is an Array of text strings.

**Save**

```
Sub SaveInTxtFile(Optional grid As Variant)

If IsMissing(grid) Then
    grid = Array(Array("test00", "test01"), Array("test10", "test11"), Array("test20", "test21"))
End If

'create object for file system
Dim fsobj As Object
Set fsobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'your path and name of text file to save
strPath = "C:\yourPath\"
strFileName = "gridSave.txt"

'create text file object
Dim txtFile As Object
Set txtFile = fsobj.CreateTextFile(strPath & strFileName)

    'populate file with grid
    For n = 0 To UBound(grid)
        txtFile.WriteLine grid(n)(0) & "," & grid(n)(1)
    Next
    txtFile.Close

'set objects to nothing
Set fsobj = Nothing
Set txtFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Load**

```
Function LoadTxtFile() As Variant

'variant to hold strings
Dim gridStr As Variant
ReDim gridStr(0)
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

    'open text file
    Open "C:\yourPath\gridSave.txt" For Input As #1
    'while not End Of File
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        'input current line of text to gridStr
        Line Input #1, gridStr(i)
        'increase gridStr to hold more variables/strings of text
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve gridStr(i)
    Loop
    Close #1

'function return grid
LoadTxtFile = gridStr

End Function
```

For more information you can see examples here: 
[How to create a .txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba) 
[Reading a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390397/reading-entire-text-file-using-vba)

And documentation here:
[File System Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198742.aspx)
[Reading and Writing Text Files](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198716.aspx)