# Send email with several attachments

Tags: vba, microsoft-graph-api

I send email without user authentication, automatic method.

```
 {
  "message": 
   {
    "subject": "Envio de email Teste do MS Graph",
    "body": 
    {
     "contentType": "HTML",
     "content": "Testando envio"
    },
    "toRecipients": 
     [
      {
       "emailAddress": 
        {
         "address": "xxxxx@gmail.com"
        }
      }
     ],
    "attachments":
     [
      {
       "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
       "name": "Teste de Anexo",
       "contentLocation": "e:\ramos.xlsx",
       "isInLine":"true"
      }
     ]
   }
 }
```

How do I attach several files to the email?

I know a parameter called attachment, but I was unable to use it to point to a physical file path. I need to point to several files.

How to transform the file into base64 using VBA? Is there an API inside Graph that does this?

Comment: As of now you cannot point out the files since `contentLocation` is not supported according to the [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fileattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). And I am not from the VBA side but you can try getting the file using this thread(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390397/reading-entire-text-file-using-vba) and you can encode the data by following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169907/how-do-i-base64-encode-a-string-efficiently-using-excel-vba) which concentrates on text file, you can give a try with Excel file

Comment: Tks, It helped a lot and solved the problem

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was that I needed to convert to base64

Answer (score 0):

As of now you cannot point out the files since `contentLocation` is not supported according to the document. And I am not from the VBA side but you can try getting the file using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390397/reading-entire-text-file-using-vba) and you can encode the data by following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169907/how-do-i-base64-encode-a-string-efficiently-using-excel-vba) which concentrates on text file, you can give a try with Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the file to base64.

```py
import base64

def encode_base64(attachment_path):
    data = open(attachment_path, 'rb').read()
    base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode('UTF-8')
    return base64_encoded
```

Define variable

```
attachment = encode_base64('c:/your_folder/file.xlsx')
```

After that you can pass to as args to JSON

```json
"attachments": [
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                        "name": "HappyCodeAgosto.xlsx",
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                        "contentBytes": attachment
                    }
                ]
```