# VBA: Run-time error "Input past end of file" when reading some text files

Tags: vba, vba7

I make use of the typical INPUT and LOF statement to read in large textiles. Some text file are 100MB and gets read in with no problem. Other smaller files give the error as in the title.

VBA (Excel)

```
'Open file and read all lines in as strings

    FileName = SumOutPath & "\" & WRYMPf & "SUM.OUT"
    Erase v
    sFile = FileName
    Open sFile For Input As #1
    sWhole = Input$(LOF(1), 1) 'This is where the error occurs some of the time
    Close #1
    v = Split(sWhole, vbNewLine)
```

Please help.

Thanks
Bennie

I checked that the file is not in use and also deleted or added a blank row at the end of the file with no success

Comment: Did you check the encoding of the files - do they differ. Without seeing your files it is nearly impossible to help.

Comment: Ike. The text files can be found here https://hydrosol-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/bennie_haasbroek_hydrosolconsulting_com/ErQp-KKBbGtMoDHYa3fzPvgBmSPaYAhrXLr9piHAeJx0Mg?e=VhJ6Gj

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76068736/error62-input-past-end-of-file-on-vba-script-to-search-directory-for-files-cont/76069535#76069535) helps.

Comment: Domenic, thanks for this. Now it reads the whole file into the string but the file seems changed. Should I still use the Split function at the top after the get function. 

    Dim FileNum As Long
    FileNum = FreeFile
    
        FileName = SumOutPath & "\" & WRYMPf & "SUM.OUT"
        Erase v
        sFile = FileName
        Open sFile For Binary Access Read As #FileNum
        sWhole = Space$(LOF(FileNum))
        Get #FileNum, , sWhole
        Close #FileNum
        v = Split(sWhole, vbNewLine)

Comment: How has the file changed?

Comment: Yes, you can still use the Split function to get an array of lines.  If the line ending is marked by a carriage return and a line feed, use vbNewLine as the delimiter, as you've done.  Otherwise, if a line ends with just a line feed, use vbLf as the delimiter.